# JPA List field without another Model

Tags: java, jpa

I would like to know if there is anyway I can do something similar to the following thing with JPA:

```
@ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
List<String> trackKeywords;
```

Or do I need to create another model with a String attribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JPA does not support such a "collection of values". Hibernate does, though, so if you're using Hibernate, you can use the [extensions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-collection-extratype) (section 2.4.6.2.5) alongside the standard JPA annotations.

```
@CollectionOfElements
public List<String> getNickNames() {
   return nickNames;
}
```

Otherwise, yes, you'll likely need to write a wrapper entity.

Answer (score 0):

JPA2 supports collection of non-Entity types. Obviously that is not a M-N relation. As per 
[1-N non-persistable](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_2_0/jpa/orm/one_to_many_collection.html#join_nonpc)